# ¿Podría añadirse la causa de cierre "pedir sugerencias sobre libreríás, herramientas, etc"?

Tags: característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas

Hay preguntas como [implementar speechContext Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/implementar-speechcontext-java) en las que se piden recomendaciones de librerías o similares.

En SO original eso es causal de cierre porque no apunta a resolver un problema específico con el código (que la pregunta de ejemplo sí muestra), sino a respuestas vagas y basadas en opiniones.

Sin embargo, en SO en español no está esa causa de cierre para una pregunta. ¿Podría añadirse?

Edito: Me refiero a esta opción:

[image: opción de cierre en SO en inglés]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a [este motivo de cierre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa2xX.png)?

Comment: @Flxtr No. Ya edité la pregunta para que sea más claro.

Comment: Desconozco la razón por la cual no exista el mismo motivo en [es.so], no obstante, de igual manera cae en la categoría de "estar basada en opiniones" y sería un motivo de cierre válido para este caso. O en su defecto, `Cierre --> No relacionado --> Otro`  y ahí describes el motivo de cierre.

Comment: Ese tipo de preguntas las suelo cerrar como principalmente basada en opiniones, dejando un enlace a [ask] o [¿Qué preguntas debo evitar preguntar aquí?](/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Gracias a Flxtr y Alvaro por comentar.

Comment: En los comentarios del duplicado que enlazo, se dice que _sólo se permiten 3 motivos, por eso dejamos de proponer la mejora de los motivos de cierre_. Dicho esto, yo tambien estaría totalmente a favor de añadirla, ya que como comenta @AlvaroMontoro las acabamos cerrando como _basadas en opiniones_, lo cual no es exacto.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien se puede usar el motivo de cierre *principalmente basado en opiniones* para muchas de las preguntas que solicitan un librería me parece que sería benéfico contar con este motivo particularmente porque da indicaciones específicas

> **describe el problema y lo que has hecho para resolverlo**

que contrasta con el caso del motivos de *cierre principalmente basado en opiniones* el cual indica

> Muchas buenas preguntas generan cierto grado de opinión según la experiencia de los expertos, pero casi todas las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica.

Nótese que este último no incluye recomendación alguna